# SwiftUI Stepper to adjust inches and automatically increment feet not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, measurement, stepper

Here is a snippent from a BMI calculator I'm making. I have two user inputs for feet and inches. In this code there is a stepper in the view that should adjust inches and, once it reaches 12, increment feet by 1 and reset inches to 0; and vise versa once it reaches 0 should decrease feet by 1 and reset to 12.

This is the main code block that I think should work. Interestingly when I make minor modifications to the logic in the if statements (two snippets below), decrementing and incrementing feet and resetting inches works properly but combining them leaves the stepper inactive once it hits 0 or 12 and does not adjust the feet.

```
struct NewMetricView: View {

    @State private var heightInFeet: Double = 5
    @State private var heightInInches: Double = 11

 var body: some View {

    Stepper("\(heightInFeet, specifier: "%.f") ft \(heightInInches, specifier: "%.1f") in", value: $heightInInches, in: 0...12, step: 0.5)
        .onChange(of: heightInInches) { newValue in
            if newValue >= 12 {
                heightInFeet += 1
                heightInInches = 0
            } else if newValue <= 0 {
                heightInFeet -= 1
                heightInInches = 12 + newValue
            }
            // Recalculate BMI when height stepper changes
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly, This code allows the stepper to adjust up properly:

```
    Stepper("\(heightInFeet, specifier: "%.f") ft \(heightInInches, specifier: "%.1f") in", value: $heightInInches, in: 0...12, step: 0.5)
        .frame(width: 250)
        .font(.title)
        .padding(.bottom, 5)
        .onChange(of: heightInInches) { newValue in
            if newValue >= 12 {
                heightInFeet += 1
                heightInInches = 0
            } else if newValue < 0 {
                heightInFeet -= 1
                heightInInches = 12 + newValue
            }
            // Recalculate BMI when height stepper changes
        }
```

And this code works to adjust things up properly

```
  Stepper("\(heightInFeet, specifier: "%.f") ft \(heightInInches, specifier: "%.1f") in", value: $heightInInches, in: 0...12, step: 0.5)
        .frame(width: 250)
        .font(.title)
        .padding(.bottom, 5)
        .onChange(of: heightInInches) { newValue in
            if newValue > 12 {
                heightInFeet += 1
                heightInInches = 0
            } else if newValue <= 0 {
                heightInFeet -= 1
                heightInInches = 12 + newValue
            }
            // Recalculate BMI when height stepper changes
        }
```

I'm really not sure why combining the two doesn't work.

Comment: Look into Measurement it will be simpler to manage

Comment: I probably doesn't make sense to keep multiple `@State` properties -- you should consider _one_ state property and make the other(s) computed properties

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are modifying `heightInInches` when `heightInInches` changes which causes `.onChange()` to trigger again and SwiftUI doesn't like that.

The simplest way to address this is to use a single `@State var` to represent your height (in inches).  Then you can extract the feet and inches for display.  Here I'm using computed vars `heightInFeet` and `heightInInches` to compute the values from `totalHeight`:

```
struct NewMetricView: View {
    
    @State private var totalHeight: Double = 5 * 12 + 11 // Initial value 5 ft 11 in
    var heightInFeet: Int { Int(totalHeight) / 12 }
    var heightInInches: Double { totalHeight.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 12) }
    
    var body: some View {
        Stepper("\(heightInFeet) ft \(heightInInches, specifier: "%.1f") in", value: $totalHeight, in: 12...108, step: 0.5)
            .onChange(of: totalHeight) { newValue in
                // Recalculate BMI when height stepper changes
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a great solution. 

I have feet as a separate @State variable because the view is quite large and also has a toggle to flip between this stepper and fields to directly input feet and inches separately. I’ll play around with this and redo some of my calculation functions to see if I can make it simpler so the variable used in calculation and this stepper is a single height in inches variable